# Are polkit and policykit tags not the same?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

What is the difference between [policykit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policykit) and [polkit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polkit) tag?

Comment: I've added the Support tag as creating a tag synonym requires help from either a moderator or a high-rep user.

Comment: Indeed, only 3 users on the site qualify for even suggesting a synonym, so we lack the required 4 users to vote on them (ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/polkit/synonyms)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Do you think it would be useful to start a new Meta question to *explicitly* ask for the mods to create the synonym?  I can see how they might quickly look at this question, see that it's been answered satisfactorily and move on (being busy people).  The other option I can think of is to edit the title of this question to make it clearer that a moderator action is desired – presuming Bahamut would be OK with this.

Comment: I don’t know the right answer here; if I see terdon in chat, I’ll get his opinion.

Comment: The `policykit` tag is now a synonym of the `polkit` tag so if anyone tries to use `policykit`, their question will be tagged with `polkit`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You’re right that they’re they same. According to the [Polkit Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit),

> Since version 0.105, released in 2015 the name of the project was changed
>   from *PolicyKit* to *polkit*.

Also, the tag wiki excerpt for [policykit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policykit) is a copy of the first line of the above Wikipedia article,

> Polkit (formerly PolicyKit) is a component for controlling system-wide
>   privileges in Unix-like operating systems.

I don’t have enough (any) reputation in these tags to suggest a synonym but I’d recommend that a moderator or high rep user change [policykit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policykit) to be a synonym for the newer name, [polkit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polkit).

Comment: Since there's only 6 questions in polkit, perhaps we could edit those posts to use policykit, then apply the synonyms?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I've edited those 6 questions to replace the polkit tag with policykit. Interestingly, none of them had an answer – aside from one self-answer.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan hang on, shouldn't it be the other way around? If the current name is `polkit`, then that's the one we should use.

Comment: @terdon Other than reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms, I'm not particularly au fait with the process of creating tag synonyms and Jeff’s suggestion made sense to me. Thanks for resolving this issue so that all questions are properly tagged.